# SQL Query Comparing A Date Against Multiple Returned Results From Same Table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am facing an issue. I want to compare a date  against multiple values in same table returned via SUBQUERY. The query purpose is to find addresses inserted by user -9 and they having their modified_date less than the modified_date of the address inserted by users other then -9 having address_type_id 1 which is Local address.

For example the query is

```
select pps_id,name
from individual_address i
where i.modified_by = -9
and i.address_type_id=1
and i.modified_date < (select modified_date from individual_address a where a.modified_by <> -9 
and a.address_type_id=1);
```

This query gives exception that this comparison is not possible as it is returning multiple rows. I know it's not correct. Can someone help me, how can i achieve the same?

**Sample Data Example**

```
Individual_Address
PPS_ID      MODIFIED_BY MODIFIED_DATE   ADDRESS_TYPE_ID     EMIRATES
1234        -9      15-05-2009      1         2
1234        1       15-05-2010      2         1
1234        1       15-05-2010      1         2
1900        1       15-05-2014      1         1
1900        1       15-05-2014      2         1
1900        1       10-07-2010      1         1
```

I want to get all records against -9 having address_type_id 1 but whose modified date is less than modified date whose users are not -9.

Thanks,

Comment: Your subquery doesn't contain any WHERE condition that links it to the outer query - are you sure you that's correct?

Comment: The subquery will return a range of dates against addresses created by users other then -9 and those i want to compare with the outer modified_date. Yes that's correct.

Comment: Could you post some sample data and the desired results? It's hard to understand your description of the goal.

Comment: You probably need either a correlated subquery or a join, but it's hard to tell.

Comment: The question is clear, the subquery does not need to have a connection with the main query as supposed by @FrankSchmitt. The issue here is to cap the range and below is the solution.

Comment: You said, you wanted to compare the date against values in a similar table. But main and subquery are both running against "individual_address".

Comment: `and i.modified_date < ALL (select ...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select pps_id,name
    from individual_address i
    where i.modified_by = -9
    and i.address_type_id=1
    and i.modified_date < (select MIN(modified_date) from individual_address a 
                           where a.modified_by <> -9 
                           and a.address_type_id=1);
```

Thing here is Address can be modified by so many users. I think you want modified_date < min(modified_date of user other than -9)

Answer (score 1):

Take the max and min dates from the result only.

```
select pps_id,name
    from individual_address i
    where i.modified_by = -9
    and i.address_type_id=1
    and i.modified_date between (select min(modified_date) from individual_address a where a.modified_by <> -9 ) and (select max(modified_date) from individual_address a where a.modified_by <> -9 ) 
    and a.address_type_id=1);
```

Comment: Thankyou so much @szakwani. I will try this sample on my production database and tell you the results.